# Qt: How to make alignment of the widget resized with keeping of aspect ratio inside the layout stretch space?

Tags: qt, pyqt

Keeping aspect ratio of QSvgWidget is very simple at first sight:

```
class ScaledSvgWidget(QSvgWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, keep_aspect_ratio=True):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.keep_aspect_ratio = keep_aspect_ratio

    def resizeEvent(self, e):
        if self.keep_aspect_ratio:
            self.resize(self.sizeHint().scaled(e.size(), Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio))
```

It works. But.
When I place it in QHBoxLayout with other elements then something unpleasant is happening.

```
    self.svg_widget_left = ScaledSvgWidget(left_file)
    self.svg_widget_right = ScaledSvgWidget(right_file)
    self.svg_widget_left.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red")
    self.svg_widget_right.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red")

    svg_layout = QHBoxLayout()
    self.bg_vlayout.addLayout(svg_layout, 5)
    svg_layout.addStretch(1)
    svg_layout.addWidget(self.svg_widget_left)

    svg_layout.addWidget(self.svg_widget_right)
    svg_layout.addStretch(1)
```

[image: wrong alignment]

Both squares must be below the text widget.

Where am I wrong?

**UPD: minimal reproducible example**

**main.py**

```py
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import QByteArray
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtSvgWidgets import *

picture = """<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="250" stroke="black"
  stroke-width="2" fill="green" />
</svg>"""

class ScaledSvgWidget(QSvgWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, keep_aspect_ratio=True):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.keep_aspect_ratio = keep_aspect_ratio

    def resizeEvent(self, e):
        if self.keep_aspect_ratio:
            self.resize(self.sizeHint().scaled(e.size(), Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio))

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.bg = QFrame(self)
        self.bg_hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.bg.setLayout(self.bg_hlayout)

        left_svg = QByteArray(bytes(picture, encoding="UTF-8"))
        right_svg = QByteArray(bytes(picture, encoding="UTF-8"))

        self.svg_widget_left = ScaledSvgWidget()
        self.svg_widget_left.load(left_svg)
        self.svg_widget_right = ScaledSvgWidget()
        self.svg_widget_right.load(right_svg)
        self.svg_widget_left.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red")
        self.svg_widget_right.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red")

        self.bg_hlayout.addStretch(1)
        self.bg_hlayout.addWidget(self.svg_widget_left)
        self.bg_hlayout.addWidget(self.svg_widget_right)
        self.bg_hlayout.addStretch(1)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.bg)
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication()
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So. Run this code and make the window more horizontal to see the problem.

**UPD2:** fixed the example above. Now it is working well.

Comment: Sorry but your question lacks lots of important elements. Most importantly, we know absolutely nothing about `self.bg_vlayout`; we can only assume that it is a box layout, so that `5` argument is certainly wrong (since grid layouts don't allow that argument count, and box layouts can only accept a further "stretch" argument for `addLayout()`, which is obviously irrelevant for your requirement). Please provide a *valid* [mre], as, right now, the code in your question is completely insufficient to give you a reliable answer.

Comment: Nothing special. QMainWindow is the base. QFrame is the central widget. Layout of the central widget is the vertical box layout. In this vertiacal box layout added 3 horizontal layouts first with "Text" button, second with QTextEdit and the third I scribed in the first post. But ok I will prepare minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're just *resizing* the widget, but its position remains the same, which is the top left corner of the geometry set by the layout manager.

Besides, calling `resize` within a `resizeEvent()` is discouraged, as it could lead to recursion (since `resize()` obviously triggers another resize event).

In reality, the QSvgRender supports the [`aspectRatioMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvgrenderer.html#aspectRatioMode-prop) property since Qt 5.15, which *partially* solves the problem (see below).

Note that the property must be set on a *valid* renderer, which happens as soon as a valid SVG content has been loaded (you cannot do it in the `__init__` if no file or data is given in the constructor).

One solution might be to add the following check in the `load()` override:

```py
    def load(self, svg):
        super().load(svg)
        if (
            self.keep_aspect_ratio and 
            self.renderer().aspectRatioMode() != Qt.KeepAspectRatio
        ):
            self.renderer().setAspectRatioMode(Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

Unfortunately, this only partially solves the issue: the SVG has a proper aspect ratio, but its size hint might be too big, making the stretches small.

In the given example, the svg has a size of 500x500, which is what `sizeHint()` returns. The result is that when the layout has a height smaller than 500 pixels but a width that would allow the widgets widths to fit it, no stretch is properly shown: consider a geometry of 1000x200, which would allow the widgets hints to fit the whole width.

The result will be similar to the following:

[image: Screenshot with size 1000x200]

This is a known problem with Qt: there is no direct way to get widgets that have a fixed aspect ratio.

Qt layout managers are intended to properly show the elements of a UI, prioritizing usability over aesthetics: it doesn't matter the size ratio of the widgets, they must be usable and the layout manager is already very busy in doing that without considering aspect ratios.

A possible solution exists, though: implement your own layout manager subclass.

The following is not a 100% safe implementation and I've not tested it with lots of different combinations of widgets or stretch ratios, but, as long as you add the svg widgets normally and use basic `addStretch()` calls, it should work as expected. Note that this only works with a standard horizontal (left to right) QBoxLayout. For right to left or vertical boxes you need to change some of the behavior, while for a grid layout you should write a much more complex implementation.

Here is the result, which is closer to what would be expected:

[image: Screenshot with same size but proper layout management]

```py
class CustomLayout(QHBoxLayout):
    def setGeometry(self, geo):
        super().setGeometry(geo)

        available = 0
        stretchCount = 0
        sizeData = []
        for i in range(self.count()):
            item = self.itemAt(i)
            rect = item.geometry()
            widget = item.widget()
            if (
                isinstance(widget, ScaledSvgWidget) 
                and widget.keep_aspect_ratio
                and rect.width() > rect.height()
            ):
                widget.resize(rect.height(), rect.height())
                diff = rect.height() - rect.width()
                available -= diff
            else:
                diff = 0

            stretch = self.stretch(i)
            stretchCount += stretch
            sizeData.append((item, stretch, diff))

        if not stretchCount or not available:
            return

        stretchSize = available // stretchCount
        delta = 0
        for item, stretch, diff in sizeData:
            geo = item.geometry()
            if stretch:
                diff = stretchSize * stretch
                geo.setWidth(geo.width() + diff)
            geo.translate(delta, 0)
            item.setGeometry(geo)
            delta += diff


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.bg = QFrame(self)
        self.bg_hlayout = CustomLayout(self.bg)

        ...
```

<sup>Note that you should generally avoid calling `self.show()` within the `__init__` of a widget.</sup>